# is there any open source autosar stack?

Tags: autosar

Can someone help with any open source autosar stack if any. I need classic as well as adaptive versions.

brief of what am doing: I need to implement this autosar stack on an Aurix Tricore lite kit.

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely never find an open source implementation of AUTOSAR. Companies provide the source code to their implementation when you purchase a license but at over 19000 pages in their requirement documents, no one would likely implement AUTOSAR free of charge, create all of the tooling, get all of the certifications and build a reputation to compete with the big players like Vector, and again, do it for free.

AUTOSAR may be an Open Standard but it is too big to justify Open Source.

Answer (score 1):

Up until 5 years ago, there was an initiative for an open source AUTOSAR classic implementation out of Sweden (Aarccore.com), but they were swallowed by Vector. Then Vector closed the implementation.

https://www.eenewseurope.com/en/vector-swallows-swedish-software-company-arccore/

There is a reference implementation for Adaptive AUTOSAR but it's intention is to test vendors implementation.

The AUTOSAR standard definition and the different implementations are basically controlled by three German companies, Vector, Etas (Bosch) and Elektrobit.

There is also simulator with educational motivation which you might be interested in:

- https://github.com/langroodi/Adaptive-AUTOSAR/wiki
- https://github.com/langroodi/Adaptive-AUTOSAR

Answer (score 1):

It was made with the whole intention to make money instead of being open. Build a closed wall for the tools, make things unnecessarily complicated in the name of easy implementation. And last but not the least keep the open source community out of this by giving them a bad name "uncertified/untested/amateur", why you ask? because existing people will lose job.

Answer (score 0):

EB provide evaluation edition for free which includes TC38XQ port.
https://www.elektrobit.com/products/ecu/eb-tresos/evaluation-package/